# Regex number pipe

Tags: regex

I got this regular expression:

```
192\.168\.[1|2|5|20]\.[0-9]{1,3}
```

192.168.2.123 -> OK

192.168.5.123 -> OK

192.168.20.123 -> Error

I want to accept just value: 1 - 2 - 5 - 20 on X --> 192.168.X.122

(the rest of regular expression is correct, i just got the problem when i try to get value 20)

Comment: Your regex, as you have written it (it has problems), [actually only matches the first IP address](https://regex101.com/r/T3pz52/1).  What is your expected logic?

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edited, i had some problem when i copy it sorry.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change what I said in my first comment.  The IP address `192.168.25.123` does _not_ match your pattern.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen True, my fault sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your observations, but here is a pattern which should meet your requirements:

```
192\.168\.(?:1|2|5|20)\.122
```

### Demo

It looks like you were confounding character classes, which are characters inside square brackets, with an alternation, which are different patterns of text, one of which needs to match.

This

```
[1|2|5|20]
```

actually says to match the numbers 0, 1, 2, 5 or pipe.  If you want to match any of these *numbers*, then use an alternation:

```
(1|2|5|20)
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was watching for. 192\.168\.(?:1|2|5|20)\.[0-9]{1,3}